# Where do I find Ubuntu User Magazine purchase from Ubuntu Software Center?

Tags: software-center

I purchased an Ubuntu User magazine in the Ubuntu Software Center. It shows as "Installed on 2014-08-25".  And the button on the right gives me a chance to [Remove]. But I haven't been able to locate the file, if a file was downloaded. Alternatively, I don't know where I should download the file from.

Comment: Have you searched for it in the Dash - the Ubuntu menu thing?

Comment: @mikewhatever The Dash is part of Unity or Ubuntu Software Center? I am currently logged in with LXDE, but could logout if I need to use Unity.

Comment: @mikewhatever You were right. I saw that button referred to as the "home button" but it is referred to right on this site as "The Dash home button" in a question. Doing a search I found out where it was, which wasn't in my home directory as I expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a search in Unity and the magazine shows up in the Applications area. I expected it to be somewhere under my home directory, but it is placed in:

```
/opt/lnm/magazines/ubuntu-user
```